# Return value of form after submit

Tags: javascript

I want to get the return value of form after submit. So that I can disable multiple clicks if it returns true. I need to disable submit button when form returns true.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the status of button disabled in the beginning
You can prevent the default submit action by using event.preventDefault() and then check for the form valid or invalid.Depending on the value disable or enable the button.

Comment: My form has some mandatory fields. When I submit the form then it checks some function which return either true or false. If mandatory field is not filled then return false. If all mandatory fields are filled then returns true. I need to find that return type based on form.

Comment: You can write something like this:
Pseudocode:
//disable the button by default
function onSubmit(event){
event.preventDefault();
var isFormValid=Validator();
if(isFormValid){
//enable the button;
}
else{

//disable the button or show errors on the page notifying user.
}

}

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the submit button by using the following JQuery script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("form#my_form").submit(function() {
         $('button[type=submit], input[type=submit]').prop('disabled',true);
         return true;
       });
   });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps.